# How to set up static site in aws using S3 - is there a visual guide?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, static-html

There are a bunch of tutorials that go over:

- creating the public bucket
- updating DNS in Route 53
- Setting permissions and policies

But they all seem incomplete and there seem to be a large number of gotchas to know.

Is there a set of screenshots to help reveal some of the mysteries to those of us who love to learn visually ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First create the bucket.
The name will need to be unique across aws so you may easily find your first choices is already taken.

[image]

For (a different) example I was able to use my initials as a prefix.

[image]

Configure options (below) - you can leave all these blank to get started !

[image]

Then find the 'Static Website Hosting' section:

[image]

---

And allow public access:

### [image]

i.e. Unchecking it (I haven't tested individual boxes)

[image]

---

It's the first option for 'use this bucket to host a website'.  Don't be confused by the Redirect requests, you'll deal with an a DNS alias for a redirect in Route53

#### Note that this is where you can see the S3 endpoint that you'll use in DNS / Route53 below.

### [image]

OK so now for Route53 which was harder to find good examples.
Note that the names are generic
The key parts are:

- Adding the 'A' record (for IPv4)
- Point the alias to s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com - and knowing that "website" is **NOT** replaced with your site name or anything.  You literally use the that exact URL that I have (allowing for different regions).

### [image]

For verification:

### [image]

### [image]

One more - here's the policy you need to add.  A critical piece:

[image]

---

One last gotcha - once you have the site working, when you go to update future content to the bucket you will see:

[image]

Know that you don't need to change that.  You can leave it as the default and the content **will** be available on the site anyway: